# Python tkinter align radio buttons west

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, alignment

I'm reading a Python script in as text and using the argparse methods written within it to create GUIs automatically using tkinter.  It all works fine apart from my radio buttons which I can't force to align west / left within a large column for some reason.  They just sit in the middle of it

My entire code uses grid, not pack, and I'd rather not change it.

```
def create_radiobuttons(self,
                        arg):
    """Creates a widget that will only accept one option
    """

    ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text=arg['metavar']).grid(column=0, row=self.num, sticky=(N, E))
    var = StringVar()
    for choice in arg['choices']:
        box = Radiobutton(self.mainframe, text=choice, variable=var, value=choice, width=self.width)
        box.grid(column=1, row=self.num, anchor=W)
        self.num += 1
    self.display_help(arg)

    return box
```

Thanks!

Comment: if would really help if you could provide a complete working example (_not_ your complete program). See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: And the example you did provide has a number of issues.  For example, grid does not take an anchor, the sticky argument expects a string, not a tuple, etc..  These types of issues are exactly why you need to provide an [MCVE] with your question.

Answer (score 3):

The `anchor` attribute goes with the radiobutton, so that the contents of the button are anchored to the left side of the widget.

Depending on how this column is managed, you may also need to add the `sticky` attribute when calling `grid`, so that the widget as a whole sticks to the left side of the column it is placed in.

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  The anchor was in the .grid() method in my example because I'd just ^c^v something I was messing around with.  My bad